# Html code not being read as a webpage

Tags: html

I think this is something simple,

this code isn't displaying as a web page:

http://summercpd.com/ophthalmic

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-]

Comment: save it with extension `.html`

Comment: Looks like you forgot your <html> tag. I'm only seeing a doctype and an If IE8 html tag.

Comment: Either file extension or due to the fact that you have a pre tag around it.

Comment: @Rasmus There's no `<pre>` tag and file extensions don't matter on the web.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that the source is converted to entities

Comment: @deceze Aaah I saw the source..

Comment: try copy pasting code in other file. Your code runs fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web server is not sending the header

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

Without that, the browser doesn't know how to display the content.

Comment: where does this piece of code go, in the header somewhere? could you please tell me with an example?

Comment: Can I add at the bottom of my htacces file?

Comment: @user3248292, what you do with your `.htaccess` file is a different question and should be asked separately, with a descriptive title and with relevant data (like current content of the file) given in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The content type of the sent document is `text/plain`, it has to be `text/html`.
Add a file called `.htaccess` in the same folder with the following content:

```
AddType text/html .html .htm
```

The file name should then end with *.html

Comment: I do have a htaccess file and it's meant to be redirecting *.html to *

Comment: This is what my htaccess says:

    `Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +Indexes
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine on

    # remove the php file extension
    #RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ /$1.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] `

Comment: No, the server sends *no* 'Content-Type` header (at least right now), so the content type is undefined. Browsers will make guesses. IE guesses right, treating the resource as HTML. Whether `.htaccess` is a solution really depends.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Before I wrote my answer, I checked the headers with Chrome's Firebug and the server *was* sending `text/plain`.

Comment: Hi I found the solution: which wasn't a problem (before my Godaddy account was hacked and I had to set up a hosting account).
The htaccess I showed above is hosted in my root folder for my overall domain, which is probably in a different server to my addon domain that I was having problems with. Doing a url rewrite for .html pages (in htaccess in the addon domain root) and making sure this extension was on all my pages worked. Thank you :-]